# how to loop code that opening the last 2 pictures in a folder

Tags: python, tkinter, streaming

i built a code that checks what is the most recent picture in a folder (there are going to be only pictures in the file), and it works about two pictures. The code is going to be some part of a larger code of video streaming and thats why i need to switch between the most recent pictures fastly.

So, That`s what i had tried yet:
this code checks twice the most recent picture and openes it via Tkinter.
What i need now is to make it a code that runs in a infinity loop and switches picture after picture.

This is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from Tkinter import *
import Image, ImageTk
import glob,os


def RecentFilePath():
    folder = "C:\\NIR"
    return(str(max((x for x in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder,"*")) if os.path.isfile(x)),key=os.path.getmtime)))

root = tk.Tk()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(RecentFilePath))
panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
t = True
def callback():
    global t
    t = not t
    if(t):
        img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(RecentFilePath))
    else:
        img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(RecentFilePath))
    panel.configure(image = img2)
    panel.image = img2
    root.after(1000, callback)

root.after(1000, callback)
root.mainloop()
```

**Thank you very much!!**

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `RecentFilePath` in your `PhotoImage` creations (`img` and two `img2` assignings).

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(RecentFilePath()))
                                                  ^^ you need to call it, to get return value
```

Comment: ok, ill fix it. but now i need to know ho to loop it for an infinity loop that will run

Comment: @J.Doe Your after method already does that. It calls `callback` every one second.

Comment: so if i have something that puts every second a new picture in a folder, this code (that i posted here) will swithces every second the picture to the newest picture?

Comment: hey, can you please answer me?? :D